# Spring/DBUnit dont rollback transaction until the end of test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, transactions, dbunit

We are using dbunit with spring boot and H2 database for local unit/integration testing. In the test we are using `TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener` and `@Transactional` annotations so that the transaction during the test does not rollback until the end.

However, I observed that if in the test I call a function with `Propogation.REQUIRES_NEW`, the rollback occurs immediately after the function returns and then test fails because it cannot find the data.

Here is the example code

```
@Test
@Transactional
@DatabaseSetup("/Uploads.xml")
@Rollback(value = false)
fun testStampSidekiqJobId() {
    uploadEntity = uploadService.stampSidekiqJobId(uploadEntity, "fakeJobId")
    // test values
}

// here is the called function
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
open fun stampSidekiqJobId(uploadEntity:UploadEntity, encodeJobId:String): UploadEntity {
```

I have tried with and without Rollback annotation. Please note that the class hosting this unit test has `DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener`, `TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener` annotations.

Comment: I doubt it is rolling back... It just cannot see it because there are 2 separate ongoing transactions. requires new (assuming that is in a other class) starts a new transcation and afterwards commits. But your test method has another transaction which might not be able to see that data (due to earlier reads) .

Comment: I see. The error I get is that the test cannot see uploads table. Do you have any advice on how to cover such cases?